# Basic number property checker

Tags: beginner, haskell

I made a small program that tests numbers against some properties:

```
Welcome to Numbers!
Is it odd? 4
No
Is it a multiple of 18? 38
No
Is it big? 100
Yes
```

That's basically it :)

My code is:

```
import System.IO
import Text.Read

askUser :: String -> IO Double
askUser str = do
  putStr str
  num <- fmap readMaybe getLine

  case num of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "That is not a number!" >> askUser str
    Just num -> return num

numberCheck :: [Double] -> String -> IO ()
numberCheck list text = do
  num <- askUser ("Is it " ++ text ++ "? ")

  if num `elem` list
    then putStrLn "Yes"
    else putStrLn "No"


main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  putStrLn "Welcome to Numbers!"
  let alot = 99999

  let oddNum = take alot [x | x <- [0..], odd (round x)]
  numberCheck oddNum "odd"

  let multiples18 = take alot [x | x <- [0..], round x `mod` 18 == 0]
  numberCheck multiples18 "a multiple of 18"

  let bigNumbers = take alot [99..]
  numberCheck bigNumbers "big"
```

Is there anything that can be improved? I was especially thinking of the `alot` number, as it is not a "clean" way of solving this. But if I don't, Haskell will continue checking the list infinitely.

Is there any nicer way of achieving this?

Note: I used lists instead of comparisons because that's what I just learned, and so you can ignore me using lists if you want to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `Integer` not `Double`

`Double` is not a reasonable type because checking if a number is big does not work with Doubles, you should use `Integer`

#### First class functions

Using a list is not a clean procedure, it does not work for very big numbers and it is slow for big numbers.

It is better to pass in a validation function:

```
numberCheck :: (Integer -> Bool) -> String -> IO ()
numberCheck predicate text = do
  num <- askUser ("Is it " ++ text ++ "? ")

  if predicate num
    then putStrLn "Yes"
    else putStrLn "No"
```

Usage is:

```
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  putStrLn "Welcome to Numbers!"

  numberCheck odd "odd"
  numberCheck (\x -> x `mod` 18 == 0) "multiple of 18"
  numberCheck (> 100) "big (bigger than 100)"
```

Comment: Thanks :) I actually only used list comprehensions because that's what I just learned ;). But why doesn't it work with `Double`s?

Comment: @Rakete1111 `Is it big? 400.321
No` Because a non-integer number is never contained in an integer range.